# Chrome vs. Firefox rendering differences of unicode characters - MathJax

Tags: firefox, unicode, google-chrome, mathjax

I'm having troubles figuring out why Chrome and Firefox are rendering some things differently. Below are images of a part of my project as seen in Firefox (top) and Chrome (bottom). [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) renders everything as the page is loading and once everything has been processed and typeset, it is displayed on the page. So I'm not sure if this is my fault of MathJax's fault. Anyway here are the images...

[image: Firefox]
[image: Chrome]

... if you would notice, the square with black border is different in Chrome, and in a bad way. Any ideas as to why this might be happening? The following is output from Chrome's console...

```
Resource interpreted as font but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml. /MathJax/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/svg/MathJax_Main-Regular.svg#MathJax_Main-Regular:-1
Resource interpreted as font but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml. /MathJax/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/svg/MathJax_Main-Bold.svg#MathJax_Main-Bold:-1
Resource interpreted as font but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml. /MathJax/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/svg/MathJax_Main-Italic.svg#MathJax_Main-Italic:-1
Resource interpreted as font but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml. /MathJax/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/svg/MathJax_Math-Italic.svg#MathJax_Math-Italic:-1
etc...
```

The code for rendering the square alone, without all the other fancy stuff, is relatively simple...

```
<div id="square">
   <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
     <mo id="tag0" class="expand">&#x25FB;</mo>
   </math>
</div>
```

... and then I tell MathJax to render it...

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "square"]);
```

... and MathJax does its thing (I have no control over the rendering MathJax does). So I don't quite know where the problem is.

I know this is a very strange and very specific question but I'm hoping someone in the Stack Overflow community might have some idea or has dealt with MathJax previously. Hopefully some brainstorming will help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The box you are seeing Chrome is the "missing character" symbol.  The MathJax fonts don't include U+25FB, and so Chrome is showing the missing symbol.  It looks like Firefox is finding the character in a different font and using that (or perhaps you have STIX fonts on the machine running Firefox but not the one running Chrome, and MathJax is using that).  Browsers differ in their ability to find alternative fonts for symbols that aren't in the MathJax fonts.

In any case, try using U+25A1 instead of U+25FB and see if that works better for you.

Davide

Comment: Ok... using 25A1 works. How did you know that MathJax doesn't include U+25FB?

Comment: Having written MathJax, I know what characters its fonts include.  :-)

Comment: Oh wow... haha... in that case I'll believe you :) kudos on MathJax!

Answer (score 1):

MathML will come to Chrome natively, WebKit has been working on it for some time now:
http://www.webkit.org/projects/mathml/index.html

I guess this question should be marked as a bug for MathJax. Hopefully soon, there would be a native solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a real answer, however rendering differences among browsers are nothing new.  I use Firefox, Chrome, Opera, IE (in that order), quite often one of the browsers renders better than the rest.  Firefox has some nice debugging plugins, you may try those (Firebug???).  Warning: You may spend a lot of effort on this.  If you get into troubleshooting CSS, ouch :).

Comment: :) I know exactly how much effort is involved in making things cross-browser compatible. I use Firebug regularly... I dream about Firebug :D